# Directory is not recognised on macOS but works well on Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: macos, finder, hard-drive, external-disk, high-sierra

I have a removable hard drive in NTFS format that is connected to macbook pro through usb.

For some reason finder doesn't show one of the directories. First I thought that I removed it by mistake, but when I opened it on Ubuntu the directory was there.

The directory is not hidden, its name written in Cyrillic without spaces. It holds some documents. There are other directories similar to this one (with Cyrillic names and files inside) but they appear in finder.

I also tried to verify it through terminal - `ls` command doesn't list this folder (however `ls` lists it on Ubuntu).

**Q:** Does anybody know what could be the reason for such a wired behaviour and how to solve this issue?

I have OS Hight Sierra with latest updates.

**UPDATE:**
Here is the `ls -alh` output from Ubuntu:

```
$ ls -alh
drwxrwxrwx 1 oleksandr oleksandr 8,0K вер  2 18:47 Папка
```

Note: I removed the other folders from the output, but they have the same permissions. The name of the folder is also changed. "вер" states for September in Ukrainian.

Here is `locale` output from my macbook:

```
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: could you add the results of `ls -alh` from ubuntu?

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy I updated the question with the output.

Comment: I think it has to do with your `locale` setting.  Type `locale` at the command prompt and post the output.

Comment: @Allan I added `locale` output.

Comment: can you do a „ls -Ol“ on mac to check if the hidden flag is set on the folder - if the output is smth like this: „-rw-r—r—  ... username usergroup hidden ... filename.ext“ the flag is set. You can change it with „chflags nohidden filename.ext“

Comment: @konqui I'll add it tonight

Comment: I should have added to check the `local` output on Ubuntu as well.  I think the issue may be that you don't have a `LANG` setting defined.  I am using `en_US.UTF-8` but I don't know which one you would use for your region.  `ru_RU.UTF-8` perhaps?  There are a number of Russian locale files - I am wondering if one of those will fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks @Allan I'll check it tonight. But note that there are other folders with the same characteristics that are visible on mac.

Comment: What happens if you change the name of the folder (via Linux or Windows) to something like `testfolder` ?

Comment: My guess is that you've found a bug in Apple's NTFS drivers. I'd try to see if you can reproduce it with a disk image or something, and send a Radar report.